# Is it possible to use web scraping to get the right words then click the link under the words?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

So I am not asking for the codes, I am just asking for if web scraping can do what I am going to describe below and where to find the tutorial:

I have a web page that contains a list of titles. Each title contains a link direct to its content. I am thinking is it possible to find the right keywords among titles then click the link of title, and finally do web scraping of the content? If yes, where can I find any tutorial about it? I am not a professional in web stuff, so it is highly possible my description may cause confusion. If, luckily, anyone understands what I am describing, feel free to edit the question body so that people are easier to understand. Thanks.(I am considering using beautifulsoup4 package from python)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, unless links are generated using javascript, you probably don't have to specifically "click" on them.

What you usually do is :

- GET the first page (using **requests** for example)
- GET all the links (using **beautifulsoup** for example)
- for each link: GET it's href attribute (using **requests** again)

Check beautifulsoup documentation you'll have plenty of examples :
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I actually viewed this page before. But I am not very familiar with the web codes so it is kinda hard for me to locate similar examples. Can you suggest some topics that may be helpful in the documentation? Thanks.

Comment: First, you should learn the basics of html.
Then look at the source of the page you want to parse and see what you need.
Then search those elements with beautifulsoup...
Look for ```find_all``` in the documentation I linked to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Selenium.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

You must obtain the path of the clickable link you need to interact, you can do this in `Selenium`.

Check the documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).